# 2.3 how create guest order on backoffice

Tags: magento2.3, admin, orders, admin-panel

1. Is it possible to create a guest order from the admin panel? It always ask for a customer or creates a new one, some customer just want to order without an account and that's possible on store front, why not possible on admin? or am I missing some config?
2. Why when orders are created on admin panel magento don't send a new order email? I know email sendig is working fine because in storefront it sends the email

Thanks :D